# Override stack.peek() to return null if the stack is empty

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

In Java, the `peek()` method throws an exception if it is invoked on an empty stack.
Currently, to get around this issue, I have to check if the stack isn't empty before calling `peek()`.

Is there a way to override the `peek()` method so that it returns `null` whenever a stack is empty instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: You can simply extend Stack and override in your customized Stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply extend your own version of stack like this:

```java
public class MyCustomStack<E> extends Stack<E> {
    @Override
    public synchronized E peek() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return super.peek();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with any class that is not final in java.  Look up inheritance.

```
public class HackedStack<E> extends Stack<E> {
    @Override
    public E peek() {
       //do your thing
    }
}
```

although you can completely avoid this by using stack#empty
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#peek()

```
public void loop() {
   Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
   while (!stack.empty()) stack.peek();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OwnStack<E> extends Stack<E> {
    @Override
    public synchronized E peek() {
        int len = size();
        if (len <= 0) return null;
        return elementAt(len - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the stack is accessed by a single thread, you should use a `Deque`. Not only does its `peek()` method return `null` in the empty case, it is also not synchronized and thus faster in single-threaded scenarios.

```
Deque<T> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
stack.addFirst(element);
T element = stack.peekFirst();
```

If the stack is accessed by multiple threads, implementing your own concurrent stack should be preferable in my opinion, and easy if the capacity is fixed.